# How can I run the official docker postgres image as a non-root user?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to use the official postgres docker files (with the aim of extending them) but if I run them as a non-root local user, they simply refuse to start.

i.e. If I follow the basic instructions from https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres and run:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
```

then I get:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
ok


Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....2023-02-18 09:55:58.427 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-02-18 09:55:58.452 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-02-18 09:55:58.525 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-02-18 09:55:49 UTC
2023-02-18 09:55:58.550 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

2023-02-18 09:55:58.603 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2023-02-18 09:55:58.625 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-02-18 09:55:58.626 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
2023-02-18 09:55:58.626 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
2023-02-18 09:55:58.650 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-02-18 09:55:58.835 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.047 s, sync=0.023 s, total=0.209 s; sync files=2, longest=0.012 s, average=0.012 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-02-18 09:55:58.840 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2023-02-18 09:55:58.967 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-02-18 09:55:58.968 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-02-18 09:55:58.969 UTC [1] LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket for address "::": Address family not supported by protocol
2023-02-18 09:55:59.017 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-02-18 09:55:59.063 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-02-18 09:55:58 UTC
2023-02-18 09:55:59.091 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

and everything is happy.

However, if I following the instructions under "Arbitrary --user Notes"

and run:

```
docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
```

(or without the it or the rm or with just the user and not the group - makes no difference)

then I get:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/run/postgresql': Operation not permitted
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "richard".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Note that [Switching Between Root and Non-Root Users in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270151/switching-between-root-and-non-root-users-in-docker) is very out of date and that the answer given as a comment under [How to create a postgres container with a non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70475045/how-to-create-a-postgres-container-with-a-non-root-user) is simply what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Running unprivileged, the official postgres image needs to run from a fixed UID - matching their image, you can't just re-use your own uid and /etc/passwd.

Try this:

```
docker run -it --rm --user "999:999" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
```

Comment: I don't understand why it has a section called "arbitrary users" if you have to use a fixed UID - that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Try attaching a volume as your pgdata, might help. It's been a while I gave up trying to change that UID. If you want an image that runs with any unprivileged UID: look for OpenShift images. I wouldn't recommend them in general, still the dynamic (per-namespace) UID is a standard, there ... while official postgres image is unusable on openshift, unless breaking its security design.